# Getting Jquery 1.4.3 and Rails.js to play nice together

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I inherited a Rails App that uses jquery 1.4.3 and is using a few plugins that prevent me from upgrading past the 1.4 series.

That being said, I need Rails.js to do some unobtrusive javascripting.  However, the only 2 rails.js files I could find were the 1.4 series that works with 1.4.0, 1.4.1 and 1.4.2 however it doesn't work with 1.4.3.  The other one requires a min of jquery 1.6 or better.

I also cannot downgrade to jquery 1.4.2 because that breaks some other plugins I'm using.

Any ideas on how to get 1.4.3 and rails.js to play nice?

I tried using the 1.4 version of rails.js with jquery 1.4.3 and there is an alert that says:

```
var jqueryVersion = $().jquery;
if (!( (jqueryVersion === '1.4') || (jqueryVersion === '1.4.1') || (jqueryVersion === '1.4.2') )){
  alert('This rails.js does not support the jQuery version you are using. Please read documentation.')
}
```

I commented that out and everything seems to work but I'm worried that there is a reason for those lines.  Or maybe it was just an oversite that they forgot to add 1.4.3 to this alert?

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: Doesnt rails 3 come with rails_ujs (rails.js) built in, you just require it in assets?

Comment: I thought so but that's not working for me.  It's possible it was removed or tweaked by a previous dev.

Answer (score 1):

I found an old version that supports 1.4.3 and the 1.5 series which I couldn't find from the github page.  Not sure why this is hidden but I found it in RefineryCMS's codebase:

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/900d714300b284d7480e1e3f09fbecf8f0e23b27/src/rails.js